# AWS SAM - how to handle a large number of endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codebuild, serverless

We're building an API using AWS SAM. Build on the Lambda Node Template in CodeStar. Things were going well until our template.yml file became too big. Whenever the code is pushed and CloudFormation starts to execute the change set and create a stack for the SAM endpoints, it fails and rolls back to the last successful build.

It seems that we have too many resources that exceeds the CloudFormation limit per stack.

I tried splitting the template file and edited the buildspec to handle two template files and do two AWS CloudFormation package commands and added another artifact. But it didn't work either. As only the first template is recognized and only one stack is created.

I can't find a way to make an automated deployment that creates multiple stacks.

I'd appreciate some input into this and suggestions to handle such a scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you get any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the nested stacks pattern. Instead of splitting your current stack into multiple parallel stacks, you will create a parent stack that will in turn create multiple child stacks.

More information [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

But I'm not sure if nested stack is the solution. I tried nesting the stacks but it doesn't play nicely with AWS::Serverless::Transform. 
I'm not able to put the SAM functions in separate stacks  and whenever I try to deploy these stacks using AWS CLI the deploy fails.

https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/151

Answer (score 1):

AWS SAM (as of SAM v1.9.0) supports nested applications which map to nested CloudFormation stacks which gets around the 200 resource limit. (AWS::Serverless::Application transforms into a AWS::CloudFormation::Stack)

https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/releases/tag/v1.9.0

Comment: But it seems (according to the error I'm getting from CloudFormation) that you can't pass a reference to the API Gateway created in the parent stack to the child stacks. They require the Api to be created in the same template the functions are defined in, so this pattern forces you to create multiple API Gateways

Answer (score 0):

The main subject to see is what is the components you have in your sam template ? is there any dependencies ? is all Functions shares the same API Gateway or not ? is all functions access DynamoDB table ?
In my case, I split the SAM by API [ API Gateway + functions ( CRUD)] in a mono repo way, each folder contains its sam template.

If you have a shared service like Redis, or SNS, SQS, you can have a separate stack with the export import Feature to import the ARN of the service.